# Why does the Dirac beta matrix commute with the angular momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, spinors

This is the Dirac Hamiltonian,

[image]

and Beta is

[image]

The question says it all, I don't understand why Beta would commute with $ \hat L$

Comment: Write down the matrix for L and you will see.

Comment: But how can I write the matrix for L? It needs to be 4x4, is there another way to do it?

Comment: What is the matrix of x, of Ly, to name a few?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588148/angular-momentum-operator-for-dirac-equation?rq=1

Comment: the matrix of x would be just x times the identity I believe, as for Ly, I'm not sure how I would construct that without using spherical harmonics

Comment: Write the commutation acting on a function. Remember $L$ act only on the coordinates whille beta does not